# Is it better to go to class, or watch the recorded lectures?

Tags: coursework, audio-video-recording, attendance

I'm in a large class where lectures are recorded and posted online.  The lectures are difficult enough that I benefit a lot from being able to pause the videos and stare at the slides for a few seconds, or even rewind the video if I realize I missed something from an earlier part of the lecture.  It's also nice to be able to pause the video if my mind starts wandering, so I can give the lecture my full attention.

However, if I don't go to class, it's easy to get behind on the lectures, and it's easy to get distracted while watching the videos (so watching a lecture online takes me a lot more time than I would have spent in class).  What do you think is the best approach?

If it makes a difference, it's my advisor's class, and the lectures are at 9 am.

Comment: I don't think there's any objective *best approach* here. Different people learn differently; we can't really say what's best for you. I feel like answers to this question are bound to be opinion-based (in the way that's *not* recommended by the [help/dont-ask])

Comment: Both. Also: read the textbook.

Comment: Note that in class you can also meet collegues (who might help you with your studies) and friends.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just go to the class. In class you can ask questions for things you do not understand or answer the instructor's questions as well. Moreover, you also have the chance to interact and get to know your co-students and coordinate assignments (for group assignments) or reading sessions.

If this was a concert of your favorite artist, would you consider watching the concert from YouTube the same as actually being there? Especially, if you already paid for the ticket (since you are officially enrolled to the class and therefore paid the corresponding fees - if any). Live interaction during a course is vastly superior to watching a lecture in your pajamas, which is still a valid alternative for people who cannot be there (sickness, online learning, free courses on Coursera). Do not miss this opportunity you are given to actually be there. And use video lectures as supplementary material as the excellent answer from @PatriciaShanahan already states.

Comment: I truly like the analogy between concert and lecture.

Comment: Several students watch lectures live in their pajamas.  It's the best of both worlds.

Comment: "large class" usually means that questions cannot be asked.

Comment: @Heutl That hasn’t been my experience, at least in classes of one to two hundred students in Australia. If one student has a question, a dozen more are probably thinking something similar.

Comment: @nick012000: Interesting. In my large classes (400-1000) students, it was just not possible. Both for time and acustics reasons.

Answer (score 10):

A combination may be best. Go to the lectures. During the lecture, if you miss something, or have trouble understanding, make a note of the time. Afterwards, before attempting the coursework, bring up the recorded lecture and view the places you missed during the live lecture.

That way, you get the keep-on-track benefit of the live lectures. You spend your viewing time in a very focused mode, looking only at the difficult parts of the lecture, which may reduce the tendency to get distracted.